# Writing data inside Android

Tags: android, file

How can I write data to text file inside an Android device?
As of now I am sending that data to server which writes it in json format. However, I want my program to write my data inside Android directly.

I want to record sensor values every time when sensors change their values. I have the following code:
What should I put instead of comment?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    switch(event.sensor.getType())
    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
 //writing event.values[0], event.values[1] and event.values[2] to result.txt
        break;
        ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? By the way it is a bad idea to store every state of the sensors except for debugging. You wast much Time and energy to save that data.

Comment: Hi, However, I can find "result.txt" FileOutputStream fOut;
String fileLocation = "result.txt";
String TESTSTRING = new String(sensordata);
fOut = openFileOutput(fileLocation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);      fOut.write(TESTSTRING.getBytes());
fOut.close();

Comment: It is for testing purposes. By the way, thank you for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
String strContent = "Write File using Java FileOutputStream example !";
FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput(outputFile, MODE_APPEND);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
osw.writeBytes(strContent.getBytes());
osw.flush();
```

Other code:

```
 File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I would not write the file everytime sensot is changed, but rather would build a String with only relevant data and write it to the file at the end of the process.

Comment: Can I use string for data? (it gives me an error when I try to use "myData" instead of data) Where is the file being saved? Thank you